# Config required for rendering non-ASCII characters in PlantUML

Tags: java, debian, gitlab-ci, graphviz, plantuml

I set up a `gitlab-ci.yml` to render diagrams but `è` (and I assume other non ASCII characters) wont be rendered.

Example :

```
@startuml
title Modèle fonctionnel complet
@enduml
```

Is rendered as :

[image]

My `gitlab-ci.yml` build job part is :

```
build diagrams:
  image: debian:stable
  stage: build
  script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get -y install graphviz openjdk-11-jre-headless wget
  - wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/plantuml/files/plantuml.1.2019.7.jar/download --output-document=plantuml.jar --quiet
  - java -jar plantuml.jar -o diagrams puml/*
```

The full `gitlab-ci.yml` & diagrams sources are available on [*my PlantUML template*](https://gitlab.com/free_zed/mypumlt) repo on *Gitlab* (not yet in `master` branch).

*My question* : Which package(s) do I need to add to correctly render non ASCII character?

*Bonus question (not mandatory)*: If you know a *lighter* image set-up to run *PlantUML* I'd like to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

Plantuml has the possibility to specify the character set to be used.
From the help information:

> -charset xxx        To use a specific charset

So you probably need:

```
java -jar plantuml.jar -charset UTF-8 -o diagrams puml/*
```

in some case you will also need `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` so

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  plantuml.jar -charset UTF-8 -o diagrams puml/*
```

Comment: Thanks, this option enable the rendering as expected, but, on my local Debian, I do not need to use this option. So I insist on my question : _which package(s) do I need to add_? Or maybe it is a configuration issue?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. When the option for plantuml does work it looks like all required packages are present, or do you mean that even when using the `-charset` option you stil ret the wrong output on your local system?

Comment: On my local machine (Debian/buster), I build the **same diagram sources** without the `-charset` option and the rendering is OK. But my local machine has a lot of _other library_ because I work with on other stuff since long time. My CI script built a minimal install, then I suppose that if the same command gives different result, this is caused by a different configuration. That is the point of my question : what is the difference between my 2 Debian machines running the same command giving a different rendering.